# How to execute Excel macro module in JSCRIPT

Tags: excel, vba, jscript

How do I execute Excel macro module in JSCRIPT (not JAVASCRIPT and VBSCRIPT)?

Double-clicking the jscript file causes the Excel macro module to run but it does not work.

I wrote jscript codes like this.

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject( "Excel.Application" );
ExcelApp.Visible = true
WScript.Sleep( 3000 );
var ebook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\※※\\Desktop\\folder\\file.xlsm" );
    WScript.Sleep( 1000 );

'The following line always caused the error.
'Although JSCRIPT opens Excel, but does not run the macro module.
ExcelApp.Run( "C:\\Users\\※※\\Desktop\\folder\\file.xlsm!Hello" );'This was no good.
'ExcelApp.Run( "file.xlsm!Hello" );'This was no good,too.
'ExcelApp.Run( "Hello" );'This was no good,too.


ebook.Close();
WScript.Sleep( 1000 );
ExcelApp.Quit();
ExcelApp = null;
```

I wrote Excel macro module code like this in "file.xlsm".

```vb
Sub Hello()
MsgBox ("Hello!")
End Sub
```

I know it's feasible with VBScript or other languages, but I'd like to do it with jscript.

Comment: Does this help https://documentation.help/MS-Office-JScript/about.htm

Comment: Are you getting any errror messages?  Does your Excel file name contain any spaces?

Comment: Check the Trust Center settings for your Excel macro.

Comment: Erromessage is "800a03ec". And file name contains no space.And I checked the trsut center settings.What should I do? I execute the macro "Hello", I see the message "Hello!".So macro is able to run in Excel.

Comment: @freeflow better yet the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/hbxc2t98(v=vs.84)).

Comment: JScript comments are `//` for a single line and `/* */` for multiple line hence the compilation errors. The `'` character is a single line comment in VBScript.

Comment: I did it. ExcelApp.Run("Hello.Hello" ) 'ExcelApp.Run("module.procedure") runs.

Answer (score 1):

I did it.

```
ExcelApp.Run("Hello.Hello").'ExcelApp.Run("modulename.procedurename")
```

This runs.Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).